# What is the $k$ to be chosen to find group velocity $V_g(k)$?

Tags: waves, mathematics, dispersion

I understand that $d\omega/dk$ represents the speed of the wave packet known as group velocity but I do not understand how a specific '$k$' account for $V_g$. In a dispersive medium different combinations of frequencies $\omega$  as a function of $k$ i.e. $\omega(k)$ combines to make the group. While finding group velocity $V_g=V_g(k)$ what is that specific '$k$' to be chosen?

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much as you selecting  one  particular $k$ to define $V_{\rm group}$, as being *interested* in the speed at which  a packet of waves with wavenumber $\approx k$ will propagate.  Think of ocean waves on deep water where
$$
\omega(k)=\sqrt{gk},\quad \Rightarrow V_g= \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k}= \frac 12 \sqrt{\frac gk}.
$$
If seven days ago  there was  a hurricane   $d$ thousand kilometers away from you, then the waves that are arriving from the storm at your location *right now* will be those whose group velocity is
$$
V_g= \frac{d \times 10^6 }{7\times 24\times 3600} {\rm ms}^{-1} 
$$
and so will all have wavelength
$$
\lambda = \frac{2\pi}{k}= 2\pi \frac{(2V_g)^2}{9.81} {\rm m}.
$$
You perceive this a [*swell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swell_(ocean)) ---  a coherent train of arriving waves all coming from the same direction, and all with the same wavelength and frequency. A sailor will easily   distinguish this  from a *chop* which are waves of random direction and wavelength. These  are generated by winds close to you. As  time passes, the arriving storm waves will be those travelled more slowly, so the wavelength  swell will gradually decrease, and then peter out as fewer short waves are generated by the storm, and  shorter wavelengths are more damped by friction.

The OP asks how a wavenumber can be assigned to a wavepacket. Let us recall the math:

Suppose that at time $t=0$ the the wavepacket is of Gaussian  form
$$
\varphi(x,0)= \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac a 2  x^2+i\kappa x}= \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int a(k) e^{ikx}dk.
$$
where
$$
a(k)= \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2a} (k-\kappa)^2\right\}
$$
If $a$ is small the packet  is wide  in space but  the amplitude $a(k)$ is tighly localized around $k=\kappa$. If the dispersion is $\omega(k)$, then at time $t$
$$
\varphi(x,t)= \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int a(k) \exp\{ikx-i\omega(k)t\}dk.
$$

As  $a(k)$ is localized near $k=\kappa$ we can expand
$$
\omega(k)=\omega(\kappa)+ \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k} (k-\kappa)+\ldots\\ \approx \omega(\kappa)+  (k-\kappa)V_g.
$$
Thus
$$
\varphi(x,t)\approx   \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int a(k) \exp\{ikx-i[\omega(\kappa )+ (k-\kappa) V_{g} ] t\}dk\\
$$
$$
= e^{-i(\omega(\kappa)-V_g \kappa)t} \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int a(k) \exp\{ik(x-V_gt)\}dk\\
$$
$$
=(phase)\varphi(x-V_gt,0). 
$$
The wave packet has thus moved through a distance $V_gt$.

Keeping higher order terms in the Taylor expansion of $\omega(k)$ will lead to the wavepacket spreading out as the different wavenumbers in the packet will have their own group velocity. You can see this by going to quadratic $(k-\kappa)^2$ order. This  still gives an do-able integral, but I won't write out the details.

Comment: Can a wave packet be always assigned with a 'k'? Say a Gaussian wave packet how do you define wavelength 'lambda' there?

Comment: I'll add the math to my answer.